# Object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
c = containers[0].resources.limits['cpu']

cpulimit = int(c.split("m")[0])
```

this works, but this code:

```
int(containers[0].resources.limits['cpu'].split("m")[0])
```

gives me :

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

`containers[0].resources.limits` has type dictionary:
i.e limits contains `{ "cpu": "500m" , "memory": "512Mi"}`

Comment: Your second sample uses `container` instead of `containers`, is that a typo here or in your code?

Comment: use this  `int(containers[0].resources.limits['cpu'].split("m")[0])`

Comment: @Błotosmętek typo fixed.

Comment: Can you put a complete code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Lafexlos I would but the code is taken from a large component communicating with a kubernetes cluster, you can only reproduce if you have kubernetes.

Comment: I wrote some code to produce the presented structure and cannot reproduce this behaviour. Have you tried all the obvious solutions like, e.g., ` int((containers[0].resources.limits['cpu']).split("m")[0])`?

Comment: Maybe try converting to string before split? `int(string(containers[0].resources.limits['cpu']).split("m")[0])`

Comment: It was the fu**ing typo!! I thought I only mistyped it here but I also had it in my code. Sorry everyone. I am deleting the question, what an embarassment.

Comment: Well, at least it got resolved. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
cpulimit = int((containers[0].resources.limits['cpu']).split("m")[0])
```

Since you are using containers instead of container in your example.